Attempt at showing an increasing, bounded real-valued function from $\mathbb R$ is convergent
Does this proof I wrote work for showing the below statement?
If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and bounded, then $f(x)$ converges as $x$ tends to $b$ from below.
Want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x \in [a,b]$ with $x \geq N$, we have $|h(x) - c| < \epsilon$.
Let $A := \{ h(x) : x \in [a,b] \}$.
$A$ is bounded and a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence it has a least upper bound.
Let $c = \sup(A)$.
Then by the properties of the supremum, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $h(x_n) < c - \frac{1}{n}$.
Consider now for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in [a,b]$ such that $b - x < b - x_n$.
Then $b > x > x_n$, hence
$$
c + \frac{1}{n} > h(b) \geq h(x) > h(x_n) > c - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Hence, $|h(x) - c| < \frac{1}{n}$.
So, as $n \to \infty$ (and we know that the interval $x$ is in shrinks to $b$ essentially, a bit unclear so how would I formalise this?), $h(x) \to c$, hence convergent.
Additionally, I never state the N that exists for each epsilon, so I have started correctly taken some possibly correct steps and a misstep and the final line is correct as far as I know.
I have have read posts like:
Prove that the limit exists of an increasing and bounded function
Which offer the proof which I entirely understand and works:
WTS for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in [a,b]$ with $b - \delta < x < b$, we have $|h(x) - L| < \epsilon$.
Let $A := \{ h(x) : x \in [a,b] \}$, note this is bounded as $h(x)$ is bounded in $[a,b]$.
$A$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ and non-empty, therefore it has a least upper bound (l.u.b).
Let $c = \text{l.u.b}/\sup(A)$.
Then by the properties of $\sup(A)$, there is an $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $x_0 > c - \epsilon$.
Let $\delta = b - x_0$.
Then consider $0 < b - x < \delta = b - x_0$.
Then $b > x > x_0 \Rightarrow c + \epsilon > h(b) \geq h(x) > h(x_0) > c - \epsilon$.
For any $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ such that when $x \in [a,b]$ and $0 < |x - b| < \delta$, then $|h(x) - c| < \epsilon$.
BUT I have made my own attempt and want to find out if that actually works. Any help/guidance is appreciated!

"Want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x \in [a,b]$ with $x \geq N$, we have $|h(x) - b| < \epsilon$." What has that to do with $f,?$ Why $|h(x)-\color{red}b|,?$ I stopped reading there.

Thank you, now corrected, it should've been c.

I don't know that is messier, your notation or the line of reasoning. Why $\color{red}h,?$ That $c$ is used before it is defined. I stop reading again. Hint: show that for every sequence $(x_n)$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ is convergent. That's all.
